# How to extract class from body element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and still learning the proper way to do things. What is the best way to extract a class from the body element?

Specifically I am trying to extract the Post ID of a WordPress page (which looks like this:

```
<body class="single single-project postid-20 logged-in">
```

So I can insert it into the new 3.5 uploader.

Comment: The new model requires a javascript pid to associate the attachment to  the correct post. I'm using Mike Jolley's script... http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for jQuery at all (it doesn't help in any way).  You can just use a regular expression on the class name:

```
var id, matches = document.body.className.match(/(^|\s)postid-(\d+)(\s|$)/);
if (matches) {
    // found the id
    id = matches[2];
}
```

Note: this regular expression is more careful than others as it requires classname delimiters before and after what it's matching (either whitespace or being/end of string).

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JcDtJ/

Comment: Assuming the script it would be used in utilizes jQuery should I still try to write in basic javascript? (I don't know...)

Comment: @mattrepublic - You should use jQuery when it makes things easier or faster and only then.  jQuery is just a javascript library so everything is javascript.  You should use the library when it helps what you're doing and not when it doesn.t

Answer (score 3):

You can get the classes on the body take like so:

```
$('body').attr('class');
```

However that will return the string `single single-project postid-20 logged-in`. You can then take that string and get the class you want by a variety of methods. I prefer to avoid regular expressions and would probably go with something like this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p6Ksd/

```
var postid;    
$.each($('body').attr('class').split(' '), function (index, className) {
    if (className.indexOf('postid') === 0) {
        postid = className;
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem. I was confused for a bit :).